# Right-aligned figure while vertically aligning subfigures with beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, subfloats

This question is almost a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328403/vertical-alignment-of-subfigures-latex). The question is asked in a comment, but is never answered.

When vertically aligning two subfigures as suggested in [section 5.4 of the subfig-documentation](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf), the second figure becomes right-aligned.

Does anyone know, how to avoid this?

**EDIT: The whole thing is top be used in a presentation / Beamer.**

An example of my code:

```
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \sbox{\tempbox}{
        \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{Figures/superleder.jpg}
    }
    \subfloat[Superleder][Superleder\footnotemark]{\usebox{\tempbox}}
    \subfloat[Neutronstjerne][Neutronstjerne
             \footnote{\url{http://westsalemhigh.com/contract/Tech2/Showcase/Stars/NeutronStar.jpg}}]
            {
    \vbox to \ht\tempbox{
                 \vfil
                 \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{Figures/neutronstjerne.jpg}
                 \vfil}
             }
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{\url{http://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Superconductor-and-Superconductivity.jpg}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with that solution using `\vbox` without extra precautions is that the box produced by `\vbox` will have a width equal to `\textwidth`; the second subfigure is "pushed to the right" by the first subfigure and this results in an overfull `\hbox` (you should see the warning message in the output console).

Now that the question has been edited to mention this is for the `beamer` class. here's an option using `\subcaptionbox` and some `minipage`s; the height of the bigger image is measured and used as the common height for both `minipage`s (if no captions are required, the same principle can be applied, without `\subcaptionbox`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newsavebox\myfigbox
\savebox\myfigbox{\includegraphics[height=6cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\newlength\FigHt
\settoheight\FigHt{\usebox\myfigbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\subcaptionbox{left subfigure}{%
  \begin{minipage}[c][\FigHt][c]{4cm}
  \centering
  \usebox\myfigbox
  \end{minipage}%
}
\subcaptionbox{right subfigure}{%
  \begin{minipage}[c][\FigHt][c]{4cm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{minipage}%
}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the alignment options for the `minipage`s one can easily achieve top, bottom alignment.

In cases like this, with the standard classes, the powerful [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package makes the job trivial, using its `heightadjust` and `valign` keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\thisfloatsetup{heightadjust=all,valign=t}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox[\dimexpr\FBwidth+4cm\relax]
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=5cm]{example-image-b}}
  {\caption{Left subfigure}\label{sfig:testa}}%
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\caption{Right subfigure}\label{sfig:testb}}
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{subfloatrow}
\end{figure}

\thisfloatsetup{heightadjust=all,valign=c}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox[\dimexpr\FBwidth+4cm\relax]
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=5cm]{example-image-b}}
  {\caption{Left subfigure}\label{sfig:testc}}%
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\caption{Right subfigure}\label{sfig:testd}}
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{subfloatrow}
\end{figure}

\thisfloatsetup{heightadjust=all,valign=b}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox[\dimexpr\FBwidth+4cm\relax]
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=5cm]{example-image-b}}
  {\caption{Left subfigure}\label{sfig:teste}}%
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\caption{Right subfigure}\label{sfig:testf}}
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{subfloatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm doing this in Beamer and when I include the floatrow-package I get the error: "Not in outer par mode. \end{frame}"
This happens as soon as I include a figure-float \begin{figure} ... \end{figure}.

Comment: @RasmusSøgaardChristensen you should have mentioned in your question that you were using `beamer`.

Comment: I probably should yes, but I didn't realize it made a difference before your answer and more googling.

Comment: @RasmusSøgaardChristensen Yes, sometimes (perhaps always) information about the class is crucial. Please see my updated answer for a possible solution with `beamer`.

Comment: Sorry about, but thank you very much for the help. Works like a charm.